# Connecting and refreshing a wireless network without restart

Tags: wireless, networking

After I set up my wireless network, I had to restart my computer before it would connect. I have talked to/read comments by, several other Ubuntu users who had to do the same thing. Why does this happen, and is there a way to connect a wireless network without a restart? Are we all just noobs and missing something obvious? I already understand the driver install process, but I just don't see why A restart seems to be necessary so often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods you can use.

To bring down all network interfaces:

```
sudo ifdown -a
```

To bring all network interfaces up again:

```
sudo ifup -a
```

To restart networkmanager:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

This also works for wired connections:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up
```