# Unable to see wireless networks on 12.10 (AR928X card)

Tags: wireless

I am unable to view any wireless networks (accessible through other devices). In the nm-applet I can see that the 'Enable wireless' is selected. Could anyone please let me know what the problem is ?

I am providing outputs for some commands which were suggested in related questions 
Please let me know if any other information is necessary.

**lspci -nn |grep 0280**

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
```

**lshw -c network**

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: f0:7b:cb:13:36:20
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-19-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:16 memory:fbef0000-fbefffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 01
   serial: a4:ba:db:ec:bf:0e
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123 duplex=full firmware=sb v2.05 ip=192.168.51.250 latency=0 multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:48 memory:fbff0000-fbffffff
```

**rfkill list**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**sudo iwconfig**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

clearwlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=21 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

**dmesg|grep ath9**

```
[   20.169143] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'ath9k_rate_control'
[   20.169414] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a network manually by clicking on the network icon, selecting edit connections, wireless, then add. Enter the network SSID, then follow these instructions to refresh the connections. [Connecting and refreshing a wireless network without restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234596/connecting-and-refreshing-a-wireless-network-without-restart/234628#234628).
You may also have to install drivers even though your computer sees the device.

Comment: I tried manual addition of networks, but it wasn't fruitful. I also tried installing the drivers through the package
linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-21-generic
(compat-wireless Linux modules for version 3.5.0 on x86/x86_64). But there was a breakdown of the system on restart after this installation (one of the displays, keyboard, mouse did not work). So I had to reinstall the system, after failing to restore the system, using a live usb. Please let me know if there is any other way to install the drivers.

Comment: This was the method that worked for me, but I'm sure that there are more experienced users who can help, sorry.